# Tensorboard: Plot loss curves of mutiple models together

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

In tensorboard, it is easy to display the loss curve of a single CNN model. If I trained two models seperately (inception-v4 and ResNet, for example) and I want to plot loss curves of those at the same time(like the figure shown below), what should I do?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGSDq.jpg)

Comment: I too would like to know the answer to this. Of course, you can save the loss explicitly to a log file and write a script to extract and plot the curves later, but it would be really convenient to be able to combine them in TensorBoard. Another nice use case would be putting training and validation loss on the same plot, for example.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think you may know a method to solve that. How do you "write a script to extract and plot the curves later"? Assuming that I have two log files separately.

Comment: Just add a printout from your loss calculation to your log file or open another file and add it there if you want to control the formatting separate from your logger (which, if you're using `logging`, means you have a bunch of boilerplate to deal with when it comes time to pull the numbers out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You can achieve this by creating two separate `FileWriter`s - one for each model:

```
inceptionWriter = tf.summary.FileWriter('/tmp/TensorBoards/example/inception4')
ResnetWriter = tf.summary.FileWriter('/tmp/TensorBoards/example/ResNet')
```

And then using those writers to add summaries for inpection and ResNet models respectively.

```
inceptionWriter.add_summary(loss_summary, step)
*
*
*
ResnetWriter.add_summary(loss_summary, step)
```

The only thing left to do is to run tensorBoard using
 command 
`tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/TensorBoards/example`
TensorBoard will automatically combine data in one plot

In my case it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMO2F.png)

BTW There is really interesting demo of basic tensorboard capabilities presented by one of google's developers
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBbEDRsCmv4&t=773s

Comment: Pretty thanks for the reply! I will bring a try based on that.